# Deleting hasMany record and saving with ember-data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have a jsbin setup with my issue:

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/sovub/3/edit

From my example, in certain situations when I try to delete a subtitle and then save, I get the error:

```
Attempted to handle event `pushedData` on <App.Subtitle:ember563:7> while in state root.deleted.uncommitted.
```

If I delete the last subtitle then save, it's fine. But deleting the first subtitle, or deleting and adding new records then saving gives me the error message.

Is it because I'm manually setting the IDs for each subtitle during `extractSingle`, like so:

```
extractSingle: function(store, type, payload, id){
    var list = payload.list
    var nid = 6

    // extra subtitles
    var subs = list.subtitles
    list.subtitles = []

    subs.forEach(function(item){
        item.id = nid++
        list.subtitles.push(item.id)
        item.list = list.id
    })
    // do the same for links

    payload = { list: list, subtitle: subs, link: li}
    return this._super(store, type, payload, id)
},
```

I've also noticed that the subtitles attribute of the payload in `extractSingle` doesn't contain the correct model whenever the error is thrown. Instead, it contains only the ID of the subtitle record.

```
// normally
id: "532",
subtitles: Array[2]
    0: Class
    __ember1403240151252: "ember562"
    __ember1403240151252_meta: Object
    // rest of data

    1: Class
    __ember1403240151252: "ember563"
    __ember1403240151252_meta: Object
    __nextSuper: undefined
    // rest of data

// when error is thrown
id: "532",
subtitles: Array[1]
    0: 6
    length: 1
    __proto__: Array[0]
```

I'm not really sure as how I should approach this, let alone resolve it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did some more research and found out about `DS.RootState` ( http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RootState.html) which is related to the `state root.deleted.uncommitted` error I was getting.

To solve it, all I did was dematerialize the record after deleting it:

```
var model = this.get('model')

model.deleteRecord()
this.store.dematerializeRecord(model)
```

This removed the records indexes (and relationships?) so it was properly deleted.

Comment: As the `dematerializeRecord` function is deprecated, use `unloadRecord` now!